# Is norm-continuous representation factored through a Lie quotient group?

Tags: representation-theory, operator-algebras, harmonic-analysis, locally-compact-groups

Let $G$ be a locally compact group, and $X$ a Hilbert space. A unitary representation $\varphi:G\to B(X)$ is said to be  *norm-continuous*, if it is continuous with respect to the norm in $B(X)$:
$$
x_i\to x\quad\Longrightarrow\quad ||\varphi(x_i)-\varphi(x)||\to 0,
$$
My question is the following:

> Is it true that each norm-continuous unitary representaion $\varphi:G\to B(X)$ can be factored through a Lie quotient group?

I.e. is there a Lie quotient group $G/H$ such that
$$
\varphi=\varphi_H\circ\pi_H,
$$
where $\pi_H:G\to G/H$ is the quotient map, and $\varphi_H:G/H\to B(X)$ a new norm-continuous unitary representaion?

An equivalent formulation:

> Let $\varphi:G\to B(X)$ be a norm-continuous unitary representaion, and let
> $$
> \operatorname{Ker}\varphi=\{g\in G:\ \varphi(g)=1\}
> $$
> be its kernel. Is the quotient group $G/\operatorname{Ker}\varphi$ always a Lie group?

I thought that this follows from the results on the 5-th Hilbert problem, but when I tried to write the proof I understood that I can prove this only in the case when $G$ is commutative or compact.

I think there must be a trick that I don't know, or, on the contrary, there are some counterexamples. Could you, please, help me?

P.S. I asked this also at [MathOverFlow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449751/is-norm-continuous-representation-factored-through-a-lie-quotient-group).

P.P.S. Perhaps, the following reformulation will simplify the question:

> Can the [group $U(X)$ of unitary operators](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/U%28%E2%84%8B%29) on a Hilbert space $X$ (not necessarily separable) *with the norm topology* contain a closed subgroup $G$ which is locally compact, but not locally Euclidean (with respect to the topology induced from $U(X)$)?

---

I am sorry, I have just understood that this is simple, the answer is "yes", see my explanations at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449751/is-norm-continuous-representation-factored-through-a-lie-quotient-group).